# vscode: Search in a directory which is outside the workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to search in a directory which is outside my workspace.

Steps:

1. I open a file which is outside my workspace.
2. Now I want to search in the directory which contains this file.
3. I use "Reveal in Explorer" and try to use the breadcrumbs, but I see no way to search in the directory.

I use Go, but AFAIK this should not matter for this question.

Answer (score 1):

As it happens another extension I wrote makes this pretty easy:  [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).

It adds three context menu entries:

```
Search in this Folder
Search in this File
Search in the Results Files (if there has been a previous search with results)
```

You can right-click on any tab or editor body and select `Search in this Folder` and it will populate the `files to include` input box of a search with that file's parent folder path.

And if you have any text selected, the query field will be populated with that selection (even if it is just a cursor in a word).

---

You could also just right-click on that tab and chose `Copy Path`, paste that into the `files to include` input of a Search and then delete the last part of the path back to the folder.

Comment: Thank you. If i understood it correctly you provide two answers in above text. Why not create a second answer for the solution without plugin?